# Slider Revolution Loading Problems

Tags: wordpress, slider, revolution-slider

I have some problem with slider revolution (wordpress). When open our website
and loading, but slider revolution stack like a half. I cant understand why happening this? I changed several time this slider another one... But still continune this problem. and also updated all things.

[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etoF9.png)

I changed slider several times, I updated all things.